# codeigniter 2 forms in one page

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I have 2 forms in one page, the Login form and the register, all fields on both forms are required. The problem is, whenever I type on the login field and hit submit, the Register field pops out its error saying it is required. here is the code for my view

```
          <?php

            echo validation_errors();

            $auto_focus = array('name'        => 'username',
                                'autofocus'   => 'autofocus',
                                'required'    => 'required');

            echo form_open(BASEURL.'home/validate_credentials');
            echo 'Username:<br/>';
            echo form_input($auto_focus).'<br/>';
            echo 'Password:<br/>';
            echo form_password('password','').'<br/>';
            echo form_submit('submit','Login');

         ?>

         <?php

            $data = array('username'    => 'username',
                          'password'    => 'password',
                          'email'       => 'email',
                          'required'    => 'required');

            echo form_open(BASEURL.'home/create_member');
            echo 'Username:<br/>';
            echo form_input($data).'<br/>';
            echo 'Password:<br/>';
            echo form_password($data).'<br/>';
            echo 'Valid E-mail:<br/>';
            echo form_input($data).'<br/>';
            echo form_submit('submit','Submit');

         ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not closing your form after opening. use CI function **form_close();** to close.

Try this:-

```
<?php
            echo validation_errors(); 
            $auto_focus = array(
              'name'        => 'username',
              'autofocus'   => 'autofocus',
              'required' => 'required'
            );
            echo form_open(BASEURL.'home/validate_credentials');
            echo 'Username:<br />';
            echo form_input($auto_focus).'<br />';
            echo 'Password:<br />';
            echo form_password('password','').'<br />';
            echo form_submit('submit','Login');
            echo form_close();
         ?>

         <?php
            $data = array(
                'username'        => 'username',
                'password'        => 'password',
                'email'        => 'email',
                'required' => 'required'
            );
            echo form_open(BASEURL.'home/create_member');
            echo 'Username:<br />';
            echo form_input($data).'<br />';
            echo 'Password:<br />';
            echo form_password($data).'<br />';
            echo 'Valid E-mail:<br />';
            echo form_input($data).'<br />';
            echo form_submit('submit','Submit');
            echo form_close();
         ?>
```

Comment: Thank you, that was a pretty idiot question after all. It works like a charm!